# Declaring MutableArray of Custome class in to AppDelegate of iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I am working on iPhone application in which i have more than 20 class and i am declaring that classes NSMutableArray into my application's app Delegate file, and accessing them from my different views.

All NSMutableArray are filled by XMLParsar requesting from server.

My application is getting slow in process, is it because i have declare in app delegate file?

or is that proper way to implement?(declaring all objects into app delegate file.)

Thanks.

Comment: I often put things in my app delegate if I want to reference it in other places. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing but it sounds like your are trying to download and parse 20 xml files at once. Which of course is going to be slow. Can you post some code?

Comment: The AppDelegate isn't a model.  The difference between putting your array in your delegate versus, say, a singleton model is that accessing the data in your delegate from a non-controller feels gross. I make it a rule not to access my delegate from anywhere.  I can't think of a worse coupling than having any class access the appdelegate for data. :-)

Comment: @skorulis : Hi, Not Exactly what you mean, i have application in which i have lots of data to request form server, data are parsed in different view i.e. Login data on loginview, movies detail on listmoviesview and so on. but for storing data for all the view i have declare NSMutableArray's in my app delegate file, and i am accessing that from different view. is that doing is good practice? if so what could be reason my application is running slow?

Comment: @ZaBlanc : Hi, thanks for your opinion, that means i should not declare any data into my app delegare right? what would be batter option to implement in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you should try to keep your application delegate as simple as possible. There are other ways how to handle shared data - singleton for example. Here's an example: http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/ There also other methods too, depends on your task and application.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, it was really help full.